# How to migrate my Android 2.2 app to Google TV

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-tv

I have an app that was designed for the Google 2.2 api (it includes maps) and I want to make it compatible for Google TV. I've been looking around on what to change to my app (by default it doesn't appear on the Google TV market). One of the things I found was to set:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
```

I added this to the AndroidManifest.xml and ran my app on the Google TV emulator and it runs fine. I also ran it on my own Google TV without any issues. However, my app still doesn't appear on the Google TV market after uploading the changes.

Is there some other XML setting that I need to change or might it even be the use of some classes that makes the market deny my app from being ran on Google TV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. I needed to add the following tag to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
```

This is used by the market to filter on. My app on a phone uses GPS but it is not required on Google TV.

Note to Google: the only way to try this stuff out is to spam current users with new updates until stuff works. They should come with a better solution to this if they want more apps on the Google TV market.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_market_filtering https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_android_features